# ASP.NET MVC Query string not showing in Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Filter", new { Area = "Music" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "body-wrapper", OnSuccess = "updateHistory" }, new { @id = "search" }))
{
      <div>
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           <input id="searchString" name="searchString" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
}
```

Area Registration:

```
 context.MapRoute(
     "Music_default",
     "Music/{controller}/{action}/{category}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Global route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{category}",
     defaults: new { area = "Music", controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
).DataTokens.Add("area", "Music");
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    //Do search stuff
}
```

Whenever the user types into the search input and submits it the Url is always: `/Music/Filter/Search`, instead of `/Music/Filter/Search/{queryStringHere}`.

How do I show the query that the user typed in into the url? The searchString is getting binded correctly, but just not showing in the url.

Here's what I have tried in the area registration, however it doesn't map to this one for some reason:

```
context.MapRoute(
     "Music_Search",
     "Music/Filter/Search/{searchString}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Filter", action = "Search" }
);
```

Here is the generated Url according to RouteDebugger when I type in the search term 'Maid':

Generated URL: /User/Filter/Search?searchString=Maid&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1462458566832

**Edit:**
RouteDebugger image, it doesn't call the correct route config because it doesn't seem to append the query string to RouteData:
[image]

Comment: Which version of MVC is this?

Comment: Since you are 5 or above, if possible I'd recommend using attribute routing instead of the route config.  This is a total side note and probably won't solve this issue, but you'll be much better off in the long run.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 1):

A browser knows nothing about your route definitions (which is server side code) and values in a `<form>` with `method="get"` are always added as query string values.

It is simply not possible to generate `User/Filter/Search/Maid` unless you were to add the route values in the `BeginForm()` method or you were to use javascript/jquery to update the `action` attribute of the of the `<form>` before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change your `Route` to accept the optional `searchString` parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{category}/{searchString}",
     defaults: new { area = "Music", controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, searchString = UrlParameter.Optional }
).DataTokens.Add("area", "Music");
```

Then in your `Ajax.BeginForm` pass the `searchString` as third parameter :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Filter", new { Area = "Music" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "body-wrapper", OnSuccess = "updateHistory" }, new { @id = "search" }))
{
  // Or pass the value as input
  <input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" value="@item.Quantity"/>
 <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: `searchString = "MySearch"` does pass into the url if I do that, so the url becomes: `/Music/Filter/Search/MySearch` but I need it to be the custom search term that the user can enter from whateever they type into the input which for some reason doesn't seem to show in url. Also that exact code woundl't work I don't think because Area="Music" has to be in third param

Comment: Tried it, still same issue. Added routedebugger image to post.